# Woocommerce product - Add text to review section heading

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to add a little text beside the heading of the review section (See image). I'd like to edit this via a hook ideally but will settle for editing the template. I've added the text to single-product-reviews.php and added that to my theme in the woocommerce folder but it does not seem to update. Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no hooks are provided for changing or appending anything to the Title, you have to overwrite this template `woocommerce/template/single-product-reviews.php` in your theme and modify the text from there.
 As you stated that this is also not working please modify
 `printf( esc_html( _n( '%1$s review for %2$s', '%1$s reviews for %2$s', $count, 'woocommerce' ) ), esc_html( $count ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );`
  it is working for me